# How to enable Windows 10 TCP keepalive?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, keepalive

As per this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/735768) TCP keepalive can be enabled by three registry values. However, setting KeepAliveInterval=KeepAliveInterval=30000 miliseconds and TCPMaxDataRetransmissions=5 definitely does not result in any keepalive packets judging by Wireshark capture.

Should it work at all on Windows 10? Is there any other way to do that on OS TCP stack level? Is it configurable?

Comment: My Windows machine NICs stay on permanently (24x7  wired and wireless) What might you have done?

Comment: @John: I don't think the question is about NICs staying on? It's about _TCP connections_ periodically checking whether the other end of the connection is still on.

Comment: No issues here with TCP staying on all the time.

Comment: @John no issues if you own all the hardware between you and remote host and know how it is configured. That's rarely the case.

Comment: Never an issue with remote connection either nearby or over VPN.